# What is the act of drinking blood called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am curious as to what the action of drinking blood is called. Its not exactly cannibalism as the person is not eating the entire body (and it also can be blood of another species), and I don't think that 'vampirism' (the actions or practices of a vampire) would fit completely here either.

For instance, is there a word that I can use, such as 'so and so is a ____' or would the best option for me to describe them as is simply just a person who drinks blood?

Comment: Are you asking about the *act* or the *person*?

Comment: What research have you done, and what were your findings? I came up with several possibilities with a quick web search.

Comment: @JoeKerr The point of my asking was to get you to [edit] your question so it does not ask for both.

Comment: I've closed this (although there are some answers) because it needs editing to clarify and add research showing what you have already found and rejected.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It was asked, if the notification is correct,6 hours ago, and closed almost as soon, in spite of a reasonable answer. Isn’t this a little precipitous?

Comment: @Xanne No. The purpose of closure is to get clarification and then re-open.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of:

1. [Hematophagy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematophagy)
2. Vampirism

Alice and Bob are hematophagous.